# Run XRM commands (CRM) from VBA - Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer

I've been trying to get this working for a couple of hours without success.

The command (when typed in the console of IE11) works like a charm:

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("fieldname").setValue ("fieldvalue")
```

From what I can gather execScript is no longer supported in IE11:

```
IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript("frames[0].Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();", "JavaScript")
```

EDIT: 
Forgot to mention, when I run the following command (from VBA):

```
IE.Navigate "JavaScript: frames[0].Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("fieldname").setValue("fieldvalue");
```

it seems to work properly, but also is quite messy. Anyone have an elegant solution? I plan on running multiple commands.

Maybe eval?

```
JSC = "frames[0].Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();"
IE.Document.parentWindow.Eval (JSC)
```

I'm attempting to run several XRM.page commands when I open a specified website, can anyone help? thanks in advance.

Sorry for the messy post. (EDIT: thanks to the mod who cleaned it up!)